# The given artifact contains a string literal with a package reference 'android.support.v4.widget' that cannot be safely rewritten

Tags: java, android, androidx

Got this error when I tried to sync my project with gradle files

> ERROR: Manifest merger failed : Attribute
>   application@appComponentFactory
>   value=(android.support.v4.app.CoreComponentFactory) from
>   [com.android.support:support-compat:28.0.0]
>   AndroidManifest.xml:22:18-91  is also present at
>   [androidx.core:core:1.0.0] AndroidManifest.xml:22:18-86
>   value=(androidx.core.app.CoreComponentFactory).   Suggestion: add
>   'tools:replace="android:appComponentFactory"' to  element
>   at AndroidManifest.xml:23:5-342:19 to override.

I made some research and I was able to sync project with gradle files after added `android.useAndroidX=true` and `android.enableJetifier=true` to my **gradle.properties** file.

But when I try to run my app I get this error

> The given artifact contains a string literal with a package reference
>   'android.support.v4.widget' that cannot be safely rewritten. Libraries
>   using reflection such as annotation processors need to be updated
>   manually to add support for androidx.

I am not using **butterknife** and adding the latest dependency of butterkinife does not help.

```
dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
    implementation 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:28.0.0'
    implementation "com.android.support:support-compat:28.0.0"
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    implementation 'com.google.android.libraries.places:places:1.1.0'

    implementation 'com.isseiaoki:simplecropview:1.1.7'

    implementation 'com.github.imperiumlabs:GeoFirestore-Android:v1.1.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:28.0.0'

    implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.8.0'
    annotationProcessor 'com.github.bumptech.glide:compiler:4.7.1'
    implementation 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.71828'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:17.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore:20.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-storage:18.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:18.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:19.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-functions:18.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-config:18.0.0'

    implementation 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-storage:0.6.0'

    implementation 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-auth:4.3.1'

    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-dynamic-links:18.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:28.0.0'

    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:17.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:17.0.0'

    implementation 'com.github.danylovolokh:hashtag-helper:1.1.0'

    implementation 'co.paystack.android:paystack:3.0.10'

    implementation 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.39.0'
    implementation 'com.facebook.android:facebook-applinks:4.42.0'
    implementation 'com.facebook.android:facebook-share:4.42.0'

    implementation 'com.cuneytayyildiz:onboarder:1.0.3'

    implementation 'com.android.volley:volley:1.1.1'

    implementation 'com.github.Flutterwave:rave-android:1.0.34'

    implementation 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.71828'
    implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.4.0'
    implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.4.0'
    implementation 'com.squareup.okhttp3:logging-interceptor:3.9.1'
    implementation 'org.parceler:parceler-api:1.1.9'
    annotationProcessor 'org.parceler:parceler:1.1.9'
    implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-scalars:2.1.0'
    implementation 'com.scottyab:aescrypt:0.0.1'

    implementation "android.arch.lifecycle:extensions:1.1.1"
    implementation "android.arch.lifecycle:viewmodel:1.1.1"

    implementation 'com.github.clans:fab:1.6.4'
}
```

I have tried **migrating to androidX** from the **Android Studio IDE** as well

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try migrating to **androidX** from android studio console and upgrading **parceler** to **version 1.1.12**

```
implementation 'org.parceler:parceler-api:1.1.12'
annotationProcessor 'org.parceler:parceler:1.1.12'
```